# Unique facebook like button for every data displayed from MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, facebook-like

I am trying to figure out how to add a facebook like button to all of the data that I am printing out from MYSQL. Right now it shows up under each data but the like button is the same for every data(If I like one, all of them are liked). Maybe there is away to connect each like button to a specific div id that will make the like button specific to that single data.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$msg=$row['msg'];
$id2=$row['msg_id'];

echo '<div class="box" id="'.$id2.'">
```

The like button

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://bookdem.com/Bootstrap-Admin-Theme-master/update_delete.php" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="true"></div>
```

If anyone know if this is possible that would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually facebook is checking the 'data-href' (url ) attribute of the like button to identify separate like button. So if you want to make each like button separate you have to give seperate 'data-href' attribute for each like button.

You can see a working demo here:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = //connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=302752836532448&version=v2.0";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
 <div class="fb-like"
 data-href="http://bookdem.com/Bootstrap-Admin-Theme-master/update_delete.php"
 data-layout="box_count" data-action="like"
 data-show-faces="false" data-share="true"></div>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        

<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="box_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="true"></div>
```